# JSON RPC call from javascript with axios

Tags: json-rpc, react

I would like to call a geth method via JSON RPC from within a react component. I tried this but I always get the Error: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Here is my code:

```
try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8501', {
        jsonrpc: '2.0',
        id: + new Date(),
        method: 'eth_accounts',
        params: {
        },
      }, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
      })

      console.log(response.data.result.address)
      console.log(response.data.result.publicKey)
      console.log(response.data.result.wif)
      console.log(response.data.result)
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
```

Do the requests have to be POST or GET?

My geth instance is running with the following arguments:

```
geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://<enode@<127.0.0.1:30310' --networkid 1515 --gasprice '1' -unlock '0x0' --mine
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the requests have to be POST or GET?

They should be `POST`.

The `GET` contains no body.

> If accessing the RPC from a browser, CORS will need to be enabled with
>   the appropriate domain set. [ref](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#json-rpc-api)
>
> The JSON RPC can also be started from the geth console using the
>   `admin.startRPC(addr, port)` command.

You should [denote](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) `--rpccorsdomain "THE CORS DOMAINS GOES HERE"`.

Pass `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the client doesnt enable [`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on the server.

Comment: I've got one more question. How can I pass parameters? I have to use clique_propose and it needs two parameters - address and authorized.

Comment: All parameters goes in the `params: {}`, you can find more here https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification